# How to implement passing of parameter to a StreamedPipeline that uses Action<Stream,Stream>

Tags: c#, action, pipeline

I read a great article on a .Net StreamedPipeline implementation on the MSDN Magazine (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163290.aspx ).

I have a challenge though.

In tthe implementation, they had it call the `Compress` and `Encrypt` methods:

```
using (FileStream input = File.OpenRead("inputData.bin"))
using (FileStream output = File.OpenWrite("outputData.bin"))
using (StreamPipeline pipeline = new StreamPipeline(Compress, Encrypt))
{
    pipeline.Run(input, output);
}
```

These methods were pre-defined **without any parameters** other than the `Stream` parameters:

```
static void Compress(Stream input, Stream output){
    using (GZipStream compressor = new GZipStream(
           output, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        CopyStream(input, compressor);
}

static void Encrypt(Stream input, Stream output) {
    RijndaelManaged rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
    ... // setup crypto keys
    using (ICryptoTransform transform = rijndael.CreateEncryptor())
    using (CryptoStream encryptor = new CryptoStream(
            output, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        CopyStream(input, encryptor);
}
```

What I am really struggling to do is how to get other,additional, non-Stream parameters to be sent to the pipeline. e.g, if it's Encryption, I want to send the keys and have that included in the pipeline calls. **How do I implement the same functionality with additional parameters?**

Comment: "without any parameters" Then I suggest you *add* parameters. Wouldn't that work?

Comment: I'm not looking at the same page you are looking... I can't find any reference to StreamedPipeline or Compress. Worse, google finds only this page with StreamedPipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the functional programming technique, [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). Essentially you can create another anonymous function that captures your arguments and applies them to your real function.

```
var additionalCompressionArgument = 123;
using (FileStream input = File.OpenRead("inputData.bin"))
using (FileStream output = File.OpenWrite("outputData.bin"))
using (StreamPipeline pipeline = new StreamPipeline(
   (input, output) => Compress(input, output, additionalCompressionArgument), 
    Encrypt))
{
    pipeline.Run(input, output);
}

static void Compress(Stream input, Stream output, int additionalCompressionParameter){
    using (GZipStream compressor = new GZipStream(
           output, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        CopyStream(input, compressor);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for also explaining `what-it-is` @Tim Rogers!... Had no idea the solution is a functional one. Always good to get a name for `what-you-dont-know`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
    byte[] key = // ... your key
    byte[] iv = // ... your initialization vector

    using (FileStream input = File.OpenRead("inputData.bin"))
    using (FileStream output = File.OpenWrite("outputData.bin"))
    using (StreamPipeline pipeline = new StreamPipeline(
        Compress, 
        (i, o) => Encrypt(i, o, key, iv)
    ))
    {
        pipeline.Run(input, output);
    }

static void Compress(Stream input, Stream output){
    using (GZipStream compressor = new GZipStream(
           output, CompressionMode.Compress, true
    ))
        CopyStream(input, compressor);
}

static void Encrypt(Stream input, Stream output, byte[] key, byte[] iv) {
    RijndaelManaged rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
    using (ICryptoTransform transform = rijndael.CreateEncryptor(key, iv))
    using (CryptoStream encryptor = new CryptoStream(
            output, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write
    ))
        CopyStream(input, encryptor);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @metadings. +1, would've marked yours if they allowed two answers, but had to take @Tim Rogers because it explained `what-it-is`. Taking nothing away from your good answer!